# Serialization formats that support tagged unions

Tags: serialization, algebraic-data-types, discriminated-union

This question has [been asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9379360/high-performance-object-serialization-library-supporting-sum-types) back in 2012 , but I'm looking for new updates.

Are there any serialization formats that support tagged unions (aka sum types)? My requirements are that it has Java and .Net client libs, and it should be "reasonable mature". Performance is not a major concern.

Avro provides partial support, but does not allow nested unions (http://avro.apache.org/docs/1.7.6/spec.html#Unions). Cap'n Proto appears to have [better support](http://kentonv.github.io/capnproto/language.html#unions), but I'm not sure if it is production ready yet. [Transit](https://github.com/cognitect/transit-format) doesn't have direct support, but does provide an [extension mechanism](https://github.com/cognitect/transit-format#extensibility) that might be able to support tagged unions.

Any other suggestions, or comments on the above choices?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Protocol Buffers version 2.6.0 added support for tagged unions in the form of [the `oneof` declaration](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto#oneof), but it looks like protobuf-net has not been updated recently so I'm guessing it doesn't support this yet.

[Cap'n Proto](https://capnproto.org) is used in production in a lot of places (e.g. CloudFlare), but it's true that the C# and Java implementations are relatively new.

(Disclosure: I'm the author of Cap'n Proto, and also of most of Google's open source Protobuf code.)

Comment: It is worth noting that "tagged union/discriminated union/sum type" in the OP's question is not supported by protobuf and cap'n proto yet.

Comment: @C.W. Huh? My answer here (dated 2015, still correct today) is explaining that they are supported. Protobuf's `oneof` and Cap'n Proto's `union` are tagged unions.

Comment: Hmm, I wasn't able to find a widely accepted definition from a user's perspective. From my understanding, the underlying data is polymorphic by protobuf or cap'n proto, but there isn't a unique identifier exposed to users. The "union" here is more akin to a C union than sum types in modern programming languages.

Sorry my last comment wasn't stated precisely. I meant like union vs std::variant in C++. See https://rainway.com/blog/2021/05/26/schema-language-unions/

Comment: @C.W. The tag is exposed -- it wouldn't be very useful otherwise. In Cap'n Proto C++, the generated class for the union contains a method `which()` which returns an enum value indicating which member is present. In Protobuf C++, `oneof`s are named, and the method `<name>_case()` returns which member is present. (These are both covered in the respective documentation.) Other languages have different ways of representing the tag but it's certainly exposed.

Comment: @KentonVarda While this doesn't quite match your Java/.NET requirements, I suggest looking at [typical](https://github.com/stepchowfun/typical). It provides the full algebraic treatment to serializing your data types.